# Does it affect performance to frequently repopulate a highly read database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, database-performance

I have a database table with about 2500 rows in, which is frequently read by my web application. Will it affect the performance of reading from that table if all of the data in it is frequently (e.g. every 1-5 minutes) deleted and re-inserted?

By that I mean:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT ...
```

Comment: Not particularly -- it could cause some fragmentation as deleted rows aren't cleaned up immediately, but nothing major, especially not on such a small table. That said a `TRUNCATE` is faster and avoids that issue to boot. Ideally you want to wrap this in a transaction so there's no moment where readers see an empty table.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "frequently".  1000 deletes per second will affect performance.  One per minute will not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff more like once every 1-5 minutes

Comment: @AGB . . . I wouldn't worry about the performance, unless you are running on a wind-up wrist watch or you have incredibly poorly written triggers on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, at the given numbers ...
However, if you have one or more index(es) on your table (to help with read/select, or automatically on any PK/UK ...) you should consider that every delete/insert may result in  re-calculation of any such index (on top of the delete/insert as such), not directly affecting table-reads as such, but adding to the overall load on the DB server.
There is no sourcecode, but it appears you are using this table as intermediate/interface to sth. else, so while 'updating' you'd probably want to make sure to bundle your delete(s)/insert(s) in transactions, best you can, rather than e.g. executing them all individually, like in a loop. Or see if you can keep your PKs and rather just update ...?
This could also help reduce fragmentation in the underlying storage ...